# How can i remove all referenceContainer in magento 2?

Tags: layout, magento2

I want create new blank page and not use any block or container from magento2. I have used

```
<referenceContainer name="head" remove="true"/>
<referenceContainer name="header" remove="true"/>
<referenceContainer name="menu" remove="true"/>
<referenceContainer name="notifications" remove="true"/>
<referenceContainer name="footer" remove="true"/>
<referenceContainer name="body" remove="true"/>
```

but still remains a number of components.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps instead of removing containers you want to create your own page layout without the containers present in the first place. If you dig around, you will find our 2 columns etc page layouts. They all start from "empty". You can just not use any of them, create a new page layout in a "page_layuots" directory (in your own module), create a layouts.xml file to register the new layout, then use that on your own page.

I do wonder why you are trying to do this and whether you really want to take over the processing of http requests at a different level in the stack - eg declare your own "area" like we do for rest and soap requests, but responding to your question my recommendation is declare your own page layout so you have absolute control over the blocks and containers on the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <referenceBlock name="header.container" remove="true" />  

  <referenceBlock name="navigation.sections" remove="true"/>

  <referenceBlock name="footer" remove="true"/>

  <referenceBlock name="copyright" remove="true"/>
```